# Pandas String Replace Error Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a bit of webscraping and would like to remove parts of a string.

```
PlayerDataHeadings = soup.select(".auflistung th")
PlayerDataItems = soup.select(".auflistung td")

    PlayerData = pd.DataFrame(
        {'PlayerDataHeadings': PlayerDataHeadings,
         'PlayerDataItems': PlayerDataItems
        })
```

The above code creates a dataframe and works as expected. In the 'PlayerDataHeadings' column there is an unwanted `<th>` at the start and `</th>` at the end of each value which I want to remove.

The code I am using is:

```
PlayerData['PlayerDataHeadings'].replace(
    to_replace['<th>', ':</th>'],
    value='',
    inplace=True
    )
```

This returns "NameError: name 'to_replace' is not defined" as an error.

Any thoughts on how to fix this or a better alternative would be great

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss `=`:

```
to_replace=
```

Or omit keyword and add `regex=True`:

```
PlayerData['PlayerDataHeadings'].replace(['<th>', ':</th>'], '', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

Sample:

```
PlayerData = pd.DataFrame({'PlayerDataHeadings':['<th>a:</th>','g']})
print (PlayerData)
  PlayerDataHeadings
0        <th>a:</th>
1                  g
  PlayerDataHeadings

PlayerData['PlayerDataHeadings'].replace(['<th>', ':</th>'], '', inplace=True, regex=True)
print (PlayerData)
  PlayerDataHeadings
0                  a
1                  g
```

With all keywords:

```
PlayerData['PlayerDataHeadings'].replace(to_replace=['<th>', ':</th>'],
                                         value='', 
                                         inplace=True, 
                                         regex=True)
print (PlayerData)
  PlayerDataHeadings
0                  a
1                  g
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, when I run your example the code works, however when I run in within my script it doesn't replace the characters but also doesn't return an error. 

Any thoughts or ideas as to why?

Comment: Hard find problem without data. But is seems you cannot replace because some difference. If data are not confidental, is possible create [pickle](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) file - `PlayerData.to_pickle('file.pkl')` and send it to my email in my profile?